# How do I handle rows that were deleted from the source using SSIS Slowly Changing Dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I am trying to implement an ETL process for our Type 1 slowly changing dimension tables in a SQL 2014 database. The load needs to happen across servers, and I would prefer not to use linked servers.

I have been looking for ways to do this in SSIS and found the slowly changing dimension wizard which works fine except that this seems to only allow either inserting new rows or updating rows where there is a match on the business key, however I haven't found a place where it allows me to handle when a record exists in the dimension table but was deleted from the source. I would like to make sure these are deleted. Am I missing something? Has anyone found a better way to handle this in SSIS?

I know that I could just dump everything into another table on the destination server and write a TSQL merge, but there just seems like should be a simple way to do this in SSIS.

Comment: Not related, just wondering, what's wrong with usage of linked servers?

Comment: You misunderstand SSIS...you would need to move the data to a table in the merging process. SSIS does not have an OUTPUT per se, but it does have an error handling method that could be used to stage the "deleted" rows. Of course, one solid TSQL MERGE could do it too, but lets assume the disparate tables require SSIS...then recognize a deleted row is a non-existent row in SSIS. However, a bad row is still a row in SSIS.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am thinking staging with a TSQl merge is going to be the best option. There are few reasons I did not want to use linked servers some around around security that I have gotten bit by in the past (other dev not being able to do something the way I had it set up and ends up putting in SA for authentication etc), but also because this process needs to be able to push to multiple servers and easily go to new ones and it's pretty simple to change connection string with package configurations in SSIS. Certainly could be done with linked servers and a bit of dynamic SQL though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would avoid the SCD functionality in SSIS, as its performance tends to be terrible - I've actually been told to avoid it by MS certified trainers, as well as plenty of people with a lot of experience. It's OK-ish on very small dimensions, but quickly tends to become unmanageable. There's a blog post [here](https://katieandemil.academy/ssis-scd-checklist) from someone who thinks it's usable in some situations, but even they suggest using a staging table for updates.

If you want to do this in SSIS you could use a Lookup to find the rows that need to be deleted (find the rows in your destination which aren't in the source using the no match output), then an OLE DB Command to delete them. But I'd give some serious thought to simply moving the data over to a staging area and doing this in TSQL, because SSIS will do it row by agonising row. Similarly to the SCD tool - it might be OK on small amounts of data, but if you're dealing with larger amounts (or might be in future), it may well become unmanageable.

If you don't want to move all of the data over to a staging area, you could use SSIS to build up a table only holding the unique IDs of the rows that need deleting, then fire off an Execute SQL Task from the Control Flow to delete them all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Most of these look up tables are fairly small, largest might be 5000 rows, but it seems like staging area /TSQL approach will be best. I was suspecting the staging/TSQL merge was going to be what I would need to do, but just wanted to check if SSIS had a magic bullet as I got a little excited when I saw SCD transform.

Comment: @schiznig - Unfortunately SSIS has a lot of functionality that's honestly more trouble than it's worth. You're right to use it to avoid linked servers and manage configuration - this is an area where it shines - but a lot of the tasks and transformations aren't optimal in one way or another. And in some cases they're more complicated to use than the SQL equivalent!